# Thread safe calling a TimerTask from within another Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, thread-safety, timertask

I have a class ABC that implements runnable. There are multiple threads of the ABC running. In each thread I want to schedule a TimerTask. The function called within this TimerTask block needs to be thread safe with respect to the variables of the thread.

```
public class ABC implements Runnable {
private int abc = 0;

public void run() {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.someFunc();
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
    while (true) {
        abc = (abc + 1) % 20;
    }



}

void someFunc() {
    abc--;
}
}
```

Is this thread safe or do I need to make someFunc() a synchronized function?

Comment: Nope.  It's not.  You don't need to make `someFunc` synchronised.  There are things (`AtomicInteger`, etc.) to handle this in other ways if you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) says:

> public class Timer
>   extends Object
>
> A facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread.

Since it runs in a background thread, it's not thread safe.

Whether or not `someFunc()` should be a `synchronized` function depends on what its doing, making it `synchronized` doesn't automatically guarantee thread safety.

Comment: Assuming this is the code that I want to run. Does making someFunc() synchronized guarantee thread safety?

Comment: If you make `someFunc()` synchronized, it will use the mutex belonging that instance of `ABC`. Since `someFunc()` modifies `abc`, you will also need to synchronize on the same instance inside your `while (true)` loop (see here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html#synchronized-blocks-instance-methods).